# Python-2.7 write to file

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I have this script:

```
f = open("/ggg/darr/file/", "r+")
a = 0
for line in f:
    if a ==58:
         print (line)
         line1 = "google.ca"
         f.write(line1)
         print line
    a = a+1
f.close()
```

I want to keep my file but only to change what is written on line 58 to "google.ca" 
then save it
using linux: mint-17.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Read data from file
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    # read all line in the file to data array
    data = file.readlines()

# change data on line 58 (array start from 0) 
data[57] = 'Data you need to change'

# Write data back 
with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(data)
```

Comment: I provided the full script in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether you want to write a new file (with print) or change the old file (with r+ mode and f.write).  You will probably be happiest if you write a new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataRead = []
f = open("/ggg/darr/file/", "r+")
a = 0
for line in f:
    if a == 58:
       line = "google.ca"
    dataRead.append(line)
    a = a+1
f.close()

f2 = open("/some/new/file","w")
for line in dataRead:
    f2.write(line)
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

With the answer of Adisak Anusornsrirung I wrote it like this:

```
with open('sss.txt','r') as file:
data = file.readlines()

print (data[14])
file.close()
data[14] = "some data here"+"\n"
with open ("sss.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(data)
file.close()
f = open("sss.txt", 'r')
print (f.read())
f.close()
```